# Create new user and enable autologon Startx/LXDE

Tags: gui

I am new to the forums and Linux in general.  I am currently running Debian Wheezy with the GUI enable.  For administrative purposes and other related tasks, I want to discontinue the use of the default user account "pi".  Additionally, I would like to autologin a newly create user to the GUI desktop.

I created a new user and enabled sudo rights via the sudo visudo command and I commented out the "pi" user account line.

`SomeUSER ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL`

I edited this file "/etc/inittab" to include the new user

`1:2345:respawn:/sbin/getty --autologin SomeUser --noclear tty1`

I edited this file "/etc/passwd" and change the "pi" user to the new user.  This change seems to prevent the GUI desktop from loading.
`SomeUser:x:1000:1000:,,,:/home/SomeUser:/bin/bash`

What am I doing wrong that is not allowing the newly created user to autologin to the GUI desktop?

Comment: I believe I figured this out. Reviewing the commands in this link [link](http://elinux.org/RPi_Debian_Auto_Login)shows that editing rc.local and adding the command su -l USERNAME -c start x Can someone explain why this works with respect to adding the "startx" command? I would have expected to see the "startx" command already in the rc.local file if I initially executed the raspi-config to enable the GUI

Answer (score 1):

I believe I figured this out. Reviewing the commands in this [link](http://elinux.org/RPi_Debian_Auto_Login) shows that editing rc.local and adding the command su -l USERNAME -c start x

Can someone explain why this works with respect to adding the "startx" command? I would have expected to see the "startx" command already in the rc.local file if I initially executed the raspi-config to enable the GUI

Answer (score 0):

Your question is rather confusing. If you are asking how to enable/disable GUI on logon execute `sudo raspi-config` where you will find a menu to set this.

Comment: Essentially, I want to stop using the default user account "pi" and use the new user account I created.  Enabling the GUI from raspi-config automatically logs you onto the GUI using the "pi" account.  How do I automatically logon to the GUI using the newly created account?

Answer (score 0):

Edit /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf

Change autologin-user to the new user.

Restart X or reboot.

Answer (score 0):

[Paul Crabb's method](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/24620/5538) of editing the /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf file works.

I used the raspi-config to enable automatically booting to the desktop with the PI user, then from terminal type: `sudo nano /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf`

find the line for autologin-user=pi and change pi to the desired username. 
ctrl+x to exit, Y to save.

reboot the pi. (`sudo shutdown -r now`) and it should boot into the desired user.